# Test-code execution order when using scalatest with FunSpec and BeforeAndAfter

Tags: scala, scalatest

This might be something that is known to most, but struck me as a surprise.

Given the following test:

```
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, FunSpec}

class MyFunSpecTest extends FunSpec with BeforeAndAfterAll {
    override def beforeAll {
        println("Inside beforeAll")
    }

    describe("Testing something") {
        println("Inside describe")
        it("should fail") {
            println("Inside it")
            fail("not yet implemented")
        }
    }
}
```

I would have anticipated output:

```
Inside beforeAll
Inside describe
Inside it
[info] MyFunSpecTest:
[info] Testing something
[info] - should fail *** FAILED ***
[info]   not yet implemented (MyFunSpec.scala:12)
```

Instead the output is:

```
Inside describe
Inside beforeAll
Inside it
[info] MyFunSpecTest:
[info] Testing something
[info] - should fail *** FAILED ***
[info]   not yet implemented (MyFunSpec.scala:12)
```

This at least with scalatest_2.9.1 versions 2.0.M5b and 2.0.M5.

The way we found this out was with Selenium tests where we created web driver in `beforeAll` - hook and used it in tests. For as long as we initialized `lazy val`s in `describe` block and used them within `it` block there were no problems since computation was delayed until `it`, in which state `beforeAll` was already executed. Problems naturally occurred the first time we introduced something that was computed in `describe` block and depended on the web driver (which was not constructed at this point).

Comment: Have you tried to replace *println()* with *info()*?

Answer (score 0):

The before() gets called before each it(), not before each describe(). Try moving your code to the it() and let us know if that helps.

Comment: Its logical that `before` gets called before every `it`.  
  
The original problem was with `BeforeAndAfterAll` where `beforeAll` is run _after_ `describe` block. I copy-pasted wrong test code (where I used `BeforeAndAfter`) to the original post. I updated the example to use `BeforeAndAfterAll`. Sorry for the hassle.  
  
I assume the confusion we had is more evident now.

Comment: Ah, I see.  What you anticipated isn't entirely unreasonable.  I see why it runs the way it does, too.  I believe we have to think of each `it()` as a test in their terminology.  Therefore, the beforeAll is executed precisely before all of the `it()`'s.  It makes no guarantees as to execution order with respect to other artifacts such as `describe()`.